# Not sure if I skipped a review or accepted the question: what happens to the review queue?

Tags: discussion, support, review

For various reasons, I've never wanted to review questions up to now. However, out of curiosity, and also because I felt it would be giving back to the community, I decided to give it a try. A couple reviews went fine, but I'm not sure if I skipped **or** accepted (I mean, clicked on "I'm done") this question: [What statistical tests to understand the sensitivity of model output](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/235100/58675).

Luckily, the question is good enough to be accepted, IMO. It could use a couple good comments, which I'm going to write, but overall it seems fine to me. My concern is that, if I clicked on "I'm done", I guess I removed it not only from my review queue, but from the general queue. In other words, no one can review it anymore. Is that so? Is there something I can do to undo this? Or should I not care, since anyway it's still possible for users who have a different opinion from mine, to flag it?

Comment: You might want to look at some of the related questions in the sidebar, like [Is there a way to 'undo' a mistaken review?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1850/is-there-a-way-to-undo-a-mistaken-review?rq=1) and [Review queue and skip button](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2581/review-queue-and-skip-button?rq=1) for example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like its still in the queue to me. (It's probably out of *your* version of the queue though)

But don't worry, most reviews take more than one vote and even if you muck up the occasional review, the worst things that will happen are totally recoverable.

For example that was a First Post review. If you accidentally okayed a bad post from there, and let's imagine it had ended up out of the queue; it would still be on the front page and many eyes would still see it. It would probably get closed anyway (a lot of my votes to close are done outside the review queues -- I try to skim the new posts every day). Someone might well wonder how it got through First post review, but unless you're doing it often that won't be an issue.

On the other hand, let's say you vote to close when it shouldn't close. It would then go into a close review and it takes 5 such votes to close it. A bunch of people would have to make the same error.

In other words, go review and don't worry so much. Allow yourself to make a few errors - especially when you start out - the system is set up to tolerate them.

If you are in a situation where you think something has happened that needs fixing, flag the post  (there's always flag/other where you can explain the issue if it doesn't fit anything else)

Comment: Thanks! This sure makes the reviewing activity easier and more robust.